# Started Mining Monero with GPU but still no XMR posted and its been about 6 days

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, gpu-mining

Here are the steps I did:

1. Downloaded Monero Wallet App for Windows 64-bit Windows 11 and setup an account
2. Downloaded XMRIG for Nvidia GPU mining
3. Using the pool: xmr-us-east1.nanopool.org:10300
4. From within the Monero Wallet, I clicked on Receive and it shows my Primary Address.  I clicked on it and it auto-copied
5. I the pasted that into the command line for XMRig
6. I started the batch file

I am running a PC with 13th Gen intel i7-13700KF 32gb DDR5 with GPU: Nvidia RTX 4090 24gb GDDR6X
It's been 6 days and still not showing anything in my Monero Wallet.  Also, I checked the P2Pool Observer and says "No shares have been reported to this P2Pool network in the past for this miner."
My speed is about 3530 H/S (as shown in screen print below)

This is the full line I am using in XMRIG:
xmrig-nvidia.exe -a cryptonight-heavy --donate-level 1 -o xmr-us-east1.nanopool.org:10300 -u {this where I pasted my Primary Account number - removed for this posting} KBa -p w=myrig -k

Am I doing something wrong or will it take longer than the 6 days that has passed so far to get something showing up?  Do I need something faster? I appreciate anyone that can shed some light.

My output shows:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve hash rate, check pool status, ensure proper XMRig setup, consider joining Monero mining communities for assistance. Low hash rate and long wait times may be normal initially.